# Grails pure sql and domain class

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

1. I have an existing MySQL database and in grails controller i want use pure SQL query instead of GORM (it's too difficult to run the reverse engineering plugin).
2. I want return json object

So my idea is, in the controller, to execute a sql query and map the result to an object and render that object in json (i have see the grails REST tutorial anyway).

To map the sql query result to an object, can i use the grails domain class or i must create a pure groovy object?

Can i use the command:

```
grails create-domain-class
```

or i must create a DTO groovy object (in  src/groovy folder)?

Answer (score 0):

If your result is simple enough, you can use `groovy.sql.Sql` class and do the querying directly in the controller:

```
def results = []
Sql db = new Sql( dataSource )
db.eachRow( "select avg( rating ) as rating, main_profile_id as id from profile" ) {
  results << [ it.id, it.rating ]
}
db.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a DTO to solve your problem you just need to use an HQL, like this:

```
def result = Domain.executeQuery("FROM DOMAIN WHERE conditions");

render result as JSON;
```

I hope this solve your problem.

Comment: Domain class are persistent by default in grails. I don't want use domain class because i don't use GORM....i think i can't use HQL right?

Comment: Remember, Grails/GORM use Hibernate to provide the basics manipulation on database, but the groovy way. So, all code do you make using hibernate you make it with GORM too. But in your case, this plugin is usefull: http://grails.org/plugin/dto

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass the native sql then you can also use spring jdbcTemplate.

### Configuration:

import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate

beans = {
..........
    jdbcTemplate(JdbcTemplate) {
        dataSource = ref('dataSource')
     }
}

### Controller:

```
def jdbcTemplate
List actionMethod(){
 String query = "your pure native query example select ........from table"
 List results =  jdbcTemplate.queryForList(queryStr)
 return   results as JSON
])
}
```

Create DTO object and map the required columns one by one .I used the DTO approach since my number of columns to be mapped were quite less.